# Tkinter script and PyInstaller

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

I can use pyinstaller to compile my script (Its a small currency converter with Tkinter GUI) and use an icon with

```
pyinstaller -noconsole -i icon.ico -F "Currency Converter.py"
```

but I can't use even without -i icon.ico.

```
root.iconbitmap(default='icon.ico')
```

with pyinstaller without it crashing

```
Failed to execute script Currency Converter
```

Im trying to make it so taskbar shows a custom icon and not default tkinter one.

Comment: I do not Exactly understanding your question, but did you add `icon.ico` to `datas` in the .spec-file? i.e. `datas=[("icon.ico",".")],`. I guess that'll make it crash if you didn't.